# Dequeuing From jQuery Queue Doesn't Work

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm expecting that the 3rd animation is going to be dequeued but it isn't and I don't know why. Here's a [demo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8251919/qu/qu.html).

```
$('#di').animate({left:300},3000,function(){//animation callback
    $('#hello').html('1st is done');
}).animate({left:0},3000,function(){//animation callback
    $('#hello').html('2nd is done');
}).queue(function(){//queue
    $(this).animate({left:300},3000,
    function(){//animation callback
        $('#hello').html('the inside queue is done');
        $(this).dequeue();
    })
}).animate({left:0},3000,function(){//animation callback
    $('#hello').html('the last queue is done');
});
```

Comment: Omg, code fart! Please indent properly.

Comment: Please restate your question as it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: the 3rd animation must be executed after the 2nd one but it didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think in terms of the order in which each function is able to add something to the queue.

Before anything has a chance to animate, the queue will look like this...

```
animate  // left:300
callback
animate  // left:0
callback
callback via queue
animate  // left:0
callback
```

Keep in mind that all this occurs before anything has started.

The trouble is that your `dequeue` is being added in the callback to an animation that takes place in the your `queue()` callback. This means that new callback gets placed on the end of the queue...

```
animate   // run, then automatically dequeue
callback  // run, then automatically dequeue
animate   // run, then automatically dequeue
callback  // run, then automatically dequeue
callback via queue  // run, place the new animation and callback on the end +
animate  //                                                                 |
callback //                                                                 |
                                                                            |
animate  // <---------------------------------------------------------------+
callback // The dequeue() happens in here
```

So you can see, that you dequeue is stuck on the end, so the queue is stuck after your `queue()` callback.

Comment: you mean that passing any function to .queue like .queue(fun(){}) 
make the passed function be at the last index of the queue array???

Comment: @Amged: Pretty much. Basically you need to remember that before any animation starts, all the synchronous code runs. So the main chain has `animate().animate().queue().animate()`. So this is what the queue will look like, but with the callbacks inserted in between. So when your `queue()` callback finally runs, the `animate()` nested inside is added to the end. Since you didn't `dequeue` directly within your `queue()` callback, the queue is stuck right there.

Comment: ...If you do `dequeue()` directly in the `queue()` callback *(and not in the nested `animate()` callback)* then you will successfully dequeue, but the nested `animate()` will still come last, so it'll be out of the desired order.

Comment: thank you that was great.
another question plz, is there is any way I can use to execute a certain index of the queue array?

Comment: @Amged: I don't think you can manually execute any one part of the queue. You just need to let it run. What were you hoping to ultimately do?

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with the queue is easiest if you use the `next` argument that is passed to the callback, but in your case, I think the problem is that you're trying to manually queue and dequeue an animation function that is itself messing with the queue.  It should work fine if you use just a normal function that doesn't mess with the queue like this and you can use either `dequeue()` or I prefer to use `next()`:

```
$('#di').animate({left:300},3000,function(){//animation callback
    $('#hello').html('1st is done');
}).animate({left:0},3000,function(){//animation callback
    $('#hello').html('2nd is done');
}).queue(function(next){//queue
    $('#hello').html('the inside queue is done');
    next();
}).animate({left:0},3000,function(){//animation callback
    $('#hello').html('the last queue is done');
});
```

But, there is no real reason to use `.queue` and `.dequeue` in this case as all the animations automatically go in the queue so you could just do this:

```
$('#di').animate({left:300},3000,function(){//animation callback
    $('#hello').html('1st is done');
}).animate({left:0},3000,function(){//animation callback
    $('#hello').html('2nd is done');
}).animate({left:300},3000, function(){//animation callback
        $('#hello').html('the inside queue is done');
}).animate({left:0},3000,function(){//animation callback
    $('#hello').html('the last queue is done');
});
```

Comment: it's not about the animation, I just want to understand the queue, and I got this problem so I want to understand why this happened?

Comment: `.dequeue()` is tough to understand (I have not fully figured it out).  If you use the `next()` argument like in my first code example, it works every time so that's how I've been successfully doing it.

Comment: another question, there is any way I can use to execute a certain index of the queue array?

Comment: Your `next()` solution suffers from the same problem as the original. That's just another way of calling `$(this).queue()`.

Comment: @Amged - I think you're having trouble with queue and dequeue because you're trying to use it with animate which is messing with the queue itself.  Either `next()` or `dequeue()` work fine if you aren't trying to put a function in the queue that itself messes with the queue.

Comment: @Amged - I've updated my answer with what I think is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: add the `queue: false` option to the `animate` call inside the `queue` function, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philippm/LbH93/).

Long answer with explanation:

The answer by @jfriend00 is almost there in the sense that the `animate` call in the `queue` function is itself dealing with the queue. Since @Amged asked for more details I thought I'd fill in the blanks in addition to offering a solution.

In jQuery each element can have a set of named queues. By default, when calling `animate` on an element the animation goes on that element's 'fx' queue. Equally, calling `queue` without an explicit queue name will put the function on the 'fx' queue.

Thus what's going on is that the `animate` call is blocked by its containing `queue` function.

The solution is to *not* queue the animation:

```
$('#di').animate({left:300},3000,function(){//animation callback
    $('#hello').html('1st is done');
}).animate({left:0},3000,function(){//animation callback
    $('#hello').html('2nd is done');
}).queue(function(){//queue
    $(this).animate({left:300}, {
        duration: 3000,
        // Don't queue the animation, otherwise it gets queued on the default
        // queue ('fx') and since we're currently running in this queue, it
        // would block
        queue: false,
        complete: function(){//animation callback
            $('#hello').html('the inside queue is done');
            $(this).dequeue();
        }
    })
}).animate({left:0},3000,function(){//animation callback
    $('#hello').html('the last queue is done');
});
```

As mentioned at the outset of my answer you can find a [work demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/philippm/LbH93/).